# static public boolean vs public static boolean

Tags: java, android

What is the difference between using `static public boolean` and `public static boolean` for methods?

I just tried both and both seem to compile fine and have the same effect unless I am doing it wrong. Which one is better and why?

Comment: Both are same in Java.

Comment: There's no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's absolutely no difference, but putting `public` first is slightly preferred in terms of conventions. From [section 8.4.3 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3):

> `MethodModifier`: one of
>
> ```
> Annotation public protected private abstract
> static final synchronized native strictfp
> ```
>
> ...
> If two or more (distinct) method modifiers appear in a method declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for MethodModifier.

Answer (score 0):

> I just tried both and both seem to compile fine and have the same
>   effect unless I am doing it wrong. Which one is better and why?

They are pretty same. No difference only first case is less readable. I think second case is more human-readable and you should program for humans so choose option that is more readable. Also by conventions you should use first.

This is similar if you ask for `null != obj` or `obj != null` both are same but first case is sometimes used but is much less readable and for me it's annoying.

`public static boolean` is more readable than `static public boolean`

Comment: More readable *as*, or more readable *than*? Note that the JLS recommends putting `public` first.

Comment: @JonSkeet hello master of masters, you right. i also prefer putting visibility of variable first and for sure than.